# bash command to copy directories from list containing directories - getting error

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a list of directories within a file and I am attempting to copy those directories to a specified destination.

test.lst:

```
dir1
dir2
dir three
```

The list is within the same relative path as the directories as well as the destination, as such:

```
/dirs/dir1
/dirs/dir2
/dirs/dir three
/dirs/test.lst
```

Command executed in ./dirs:

```
cat test.lst | xargs -I {} cp -R {} ./_DEST
```

Expected result:

```
Directories in list copied from /dirs to /dirs/_DEST
```

Actual Result:

```
[.../dirs] # cat test.lst | xargs -I {} cp -R {} ./_DEST
cp: cannot stat `dir1\r': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `dir2\r': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `dir three\r': No such file or directory
```

I have tried adding the full path into the list for each directory (i.e '/...dirs/dir1'), but no help.
all dirs have been relaxed to 777 and are owned by same user/group that is executing the command.

Comment: Try the command `dos2unix test.lst` to remove the `\r`s.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that would have done it too, but I already stripped with sed.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate issue is that your `test.lst` file appears to have DOS-style CRLF line endings (CR is denoted by the `\r` escape char).

You could convert the file with `dos2unix`, however instead of using `cat` and `xargs -I {}` I'd suggest removing the CR with `sed` then setting the `xargs` delimiter to newline ex.

```
sed 's/\r$//' test.lst | xargs -d '\n' cp -Rt ./_DEST --
```

Comment: You are correct.  Thank you!

Comment: @ctroyp The best way to say thanks and indicate correctness is to accept the answer and/or vote on it.